# Can't log in to Tomcat Manager GUI (keeps refreshing)

Tags: tomcat, tomcat-manager

I'm trying to log into the tomcat manager GUI, but when I enter my credentials the page just refreshes.
This is the relevant piece of my tomcat-users.xml file:

```
<role rolename="manager-gui"/>
<role rolename="manager-script"/>
<user username="admin" password="password" roles="manager-gui,manager-script" />
```

What does the page refreshing when I enter credentials mean?

Answer (score 0):

The manager GUI wasn't working. Running catalina configtest from the command line showed that tomcat had some permissions issues, and running startup as an administrator solved them and got the manager GUI running.